# Cast void* to struct result to bad values

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting, esp32

I'm a newbie in C and obviously I have problems :D

I want to cast a `void*` to a struct.
Here is my code:

```c
struct temp_config {
    float min_temp;
    float max_temp;
};

temp_config temp_config_ = {
    .min_temp = 22.0,
    .max_temp = 27.0,
};
```

```c
void on_temp_conf_update(void* handler_args, esp_event_base_t base, int32_t event, void* event_data) {
    temp_config *temp_config_ = (struct temp_config*)event_data;
    ESP_LOGI(CONFIG_LOG_TAG, "CONF MAX TEMP %f", temp_config_->max_temp);
    ESP_LOGI(CONFIG_LOG_TAG, "CONF MIN TEMP %f", temp_config_->min_temp);
}
```

The result of `temp_config_->max_temp` is `-0.001322` 
And the result of `temp_config_->min_temp` is `1.977762`

I would like to understand why the results are not the same.

Many Thanks for your help :)

**EDIT**

More details:

Here the lamba where I initialize the struct and dispatch the event:

```c
server.on("/api/temp", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
      if (!request->hasParam("max_temp", true) && !request->hasParam("max_temp", true)) {
        request->send(400, "application/json", "{\"message\": \"min_temp and max_temp are required\"}");
        return;
      }

      temp_config temp_config_ = {
        .min_temp = atof(request->getParam("min_temp", true)->value().c_str()),
        .max_temp = atof(request->getParam("max_temp", true)->value().c_str()),
      };

      event_loop_dispatch(MG_EVENT_CONF_TEMP_MUST_UPDATE, &temp_config_);

      request->send(200, "application/json", "{\"message\": \"temp_updated\"}");
  });
```

here the definition of `event_loop_dispatch`

```c
void event_loop_dispatch(mg_event event, void* event_data) {
    esp_event_post_to(mg_events_loop, MG_EVENTS, event, &event_data, sizeof(event_data), portMAX_DELAY);
}
```

and here, the event handler:

```c
void on_temp_conf_update(void* handler_args, esp_event_base_t base, int32_t event, void* event_data) {
    ESP_LOGI(CONFIG_LOG_TAG, "temperature conf must update");
    temp_config *temp_config_ = (struct temp_config*)event_data;
    ESP_LOGI(CONFIG_LOG_TAG, "CONF MAX TEMP %f", temp_config_->max_temp);
    ESP_LOGI(CONFIG_LOG_TAG, "CONF MIN TEMP %f", temp_config_->min_temp);
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess `temp_config_` is local to some function that passes its address as an argument to some registration along with `on_temp_conf_update` as a callback?

Comment: exactly, like this `event_loop_dispatch(MG_EVENT_CONF_TEMP_MUST_UPDATE, &temp_config_);`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Or as close to one as you can. There is too much missing to post an actual answer. I have a hunch, but I would rather it be substantiated.

Comment: @Strnoar A local variable ceases to exist when it goes out of scope.  In most cases, that means when the function it's defined in returns.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've edited the original question :)

Comment: I updated my code like below:

`void event_loop_dispatch(mg_event event, void* event_data) {
    esp_event_post_to(mg_events_loop, MG_EVENTS, event, event_data, sizeof(event_data), portMAX_DELAY);
}`

I pass `event_data` instead of `&event_data`, It is better, I can have the correct `min_temp`, but the `max_temp` still wrong